# SQL Server data raises truncating error when exporting to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm trying to export my SQL data to an Excel file and I'm getting a truncating error because of the exceeded character's length from one of my SQL table's columns. But when I import from Excel into SQL, I get the complete value from Excel even one of its column is exceeded to 255 in its length.

I tried to set the `ImportMixedTypes` registry of `LOCAL_MACHINE` to Majority Type but no  luck. I need to transfer the data to Excel file so it can be easily read. I hope somebody could give me hint or idea to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you have a column that more than 255 in length when exporting to excel? if so do you want truncate it or do you have other requirement?

Comment: How are you doing the export? Might be easier to export to csv.

Comment: @AdinugrahaTawaqal - Yes I have a lengthy column that exceeds 255 characters. And I need that column not to truncate in the excel file.

Comment: @TomC - so far I tried using the export wizard and the openrowset but I still get a truncating error..

Comment: as @TomC suggest could you import and export in csv? if you have  to use excel read here https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/860660/Excel-source-having-more-than-255-characters?PageIndex=2